# Can't pair to Mac in Version 17.2.0 Preview 4.0

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2022, maui

Downloaded the Visual Studio Version 17.2.0 Preview 4.0. Created a new Maui project. It won't pair to my Mac. Unloaded the project. It pairs to the Mac.

Went back to Visual Studio Version Version 17.1.5 (non Preview) and it connects just fine to the Mac.

The one major clue I have is - if you go to the Options->Options->Xamarin->iOS Settings - the XCode Path is trashed. There's nothing there after you load a Maui project.

Anyone else see this? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Are xcode and VS Mac up-to-date on the mac? I always update xcode, run it - sometimes it asks to download dependencies - say yes (xamarin needs something in dependencies), open its preferences, make sure my apple id is signed in. Then update VS Mac (if not already updated). Build a project locally in vs mac. Run locally on simulator. Then reboot mac and pc. Usually this sequence of actions fixes any weird problems related to xamarin development - maybe will help maui too.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - Yeah, thanks. Done all that. The issue here is that XCode works just fine with the non-preview version of VS 2022, so we know that XCode is in the right place. But just to be sure, I uninstalled the last version and reinstalled the latest this morning.